# Php Yii, How to register for a event raised by a controller

Tags: php, events, yii

What I want to do: Register a component to an event raised by a controller.

In my config main.php:

```
'preload' => array(MessageConsumer) // actually an impl class of interface
```

In my MessageConsumer impl

```
public function init() {
    Yii::app()->getController()->onMessageReceived = array($this, 'onMessageReceived');
}
```

Expected result: when the init method fires the consumer is registered to the current controller.

Actual result: there's no current controller yet. It seems the pre-load is performed before the webapplication does the controller magic.

So I tried something like:
In my MessageConsumer impl:

```
public function init() {
    $self = $this;
    Yii::app()->onBeginRequest(function() use ($self) {
        $controller = Yii::app()->getController();
        if($controller instanceof MessagingController) {
            Yii::app()->getController()->onMessageReceived = array($self, 'onMessageReceived');
        }
    });
}
```

Which doesn't work either because it seems the init() is called after the onBeginRequest() event is raised by the webapp.

Is there a way to register to events raised by a controller without explicitly linking the component to the controller class? Obviously I could register the listener in the constructor of the controller but I want to loosely couple the 2 components by using configuration.

Maybe there's some event like "onComponentLoaded" for which I could register? Since a Controller is a component I'd expect the Yii core to fire the event whenever there's a component loaded if there's such an event at all.

Comment: in general for what purpose are you using the event can you tell it in brief ??

Comment: The generic purpose is to decouple the event producer and the listener. But the specific purpose here is to notify listeners that a certain controller method has been called.

I suppose since php does not implement multi-threading I would be better off pushing a message on an eventbus. A Die() in one of the listener methods would kill the system so its not very robust this way.

Comment: have you ever solved this issue ? i have the exact same issue ...

Comment: No I did not solve this issue. It seemed to me that Yii is not designed for this purpose. Instead I integrated a messagebus in my system for deferred processing of the received message.

Comment: Did you try http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/static-events/ ? I've tried, but event was not handled properly when attached to controller's class. What a pity Yii doesn't support it. Actually I think that events in Yii are implemented very bad..

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is what you looking for, the `onBeforeAction()`;

```
<?php
class YourController extends Controller
{
    //this action is executed before any controller action
    protected function beforeAction($action)
    {
        //do stuff before controll action
        return true;
    }

    //the rest ofyour controller actions and stuff
    public function actionIndex(){
        //[...]
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not really. The purpose of raising an event is to decouple the controller from any listener component. What I'm looking for is a solution to loosely couple a listener to an event producing controller. If I'd use the beforeAction() method to register the lister I'd tightly couple them.